# Spark Driver quitted suddenly without any warn, exception in kubernetes spark operator

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I've developed spark kotlin application. It runs well in local environment but in Kubernetes, driver quitted while executor downloading jar in S3.
I tried to extend resources (only memory to 4G but this applicaton uses less than 1G) and timeouts (can seen in below sparkconf)
Would anyone can guess why?

Below is log near doStop of Jetty (http server for spark)

```
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ContainerLifeCycle: ContextHandlerCollection@bfe47a8{STARTED} added {GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STOPPED,min=32,inflate=-1},UNMANAGED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50e0b472{/static/sql,null,STOPPED,@Spark}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractHandler: starting o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50e0b472{/static/sql,null,STARTING,@Spark}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting SymlinkAllowedResourceAliasChecker@45017263{base=null,protected=null}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47202ms SymlinkAllowedResourceAliasChecker@45017263{base=null,protected=null}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting ServletHandler@32a074ed{STOPPED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: Path=/[EMBEDDED:null] mapped to servlet=org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef[EMBEDDED:null]
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG PathMappings: Added MappedResource[pathSpec=ServletPathSpec@ad2678ee{/},resource=org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef==org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@753d27d2{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STOPPED}] to PathMappings[size=1]
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG PathMappings: Added MappedResource[pathSpec=ServletPathSpec@ad2678ee{/},resource=org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef==org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@753d27d2{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STOPPED}] to PathMappings[size=1]
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: filterNameMap={org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100=org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100==org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter@29eaf100{inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null}}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: pathFilters=[[/*]/[]/[INCLUDE, ERROR, FORWARD, REQUEST, ASYNC]=>org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100]
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: servletFilterMap={}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: servletPathMap=PathMappings[size=1]
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: servletNameMap={org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef=org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef==org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@753d27d2{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STOPPED}}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractHandler: starting ServletHandler@32a074ed{STARTING}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: filterNameMap={org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100=org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100==org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter@29eaf100{inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null}}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: pathFilters=[[/*]/[]/[INCLUDE, ERROR, FORWARD, REQUEST, ASYNC]=>org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100]
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: servletFilterMap={}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: servletPathMap=PathMappings[size=1]
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHandler: servletNameMap={org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef=org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef==org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@753d27d2{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STOPPED}}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractHandler: starting ServletHandler@32a074ed{STARTING}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47204ms ServletHandler@32a074ed{STARTED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47204ms ServletHandler@32a074ed{STARTED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100==org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter@29eaf100{inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47204ms org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100==org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter@29eaf100{inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG FilterHolder: Filter.init org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter@a6204e4
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef==org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@753d27d2{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STOPPED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47205ms org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef==org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@753d27d2{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STARTED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100==org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter@29eaf100{inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47204ms org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter-29eaf100==org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter@29eaf100{inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG FilterHolder: Filter.init org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter@a6204e4
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef==org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@753d27d2{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STOPPED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47205ms org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef==org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet@753d27d2{jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STARTED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHolder: Servlet.init null for org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ServletHolder: Servlet.init null for org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-673605ef
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG DefaultServlet: resource base = jar:file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-sql_2.12-3.3.1.jar!/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/ui/static
23/10/16 07:37:40 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50e0b472{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47205ms o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50e0b472{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG DefaultServlet: resource base = jar:file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-sql_2.12-3.3.1.jar!/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/ui/static
23/10/16 07:37:40 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50e0b472{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47205ms o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50e0b472{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STOPPED,min=32,inflate=-1}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STOPPED,min=32,inflate=-1}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ContainerLifeCycle: GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STARTING,min=32,inflate=-1} added {DeflaterPool@4b360a82{STOPPED,size=0,capacity=UNLIMITED},AUTO}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG ContainerLifeCycle: GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STARTING,min=32,inflate=-1} added {DeflaterPool@4b360a82{STOPPED,size=0,capacity=UNLIMITED},AUTO}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractHandler: starting GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STARTING,min=32,inflate=-1}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting DeflaterPool@4b360a82{STOPPED,size=0,capacity=UNLIMITED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractHandler: starting GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STARTING,min=32,inflate=-1}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: starting DeflaterPool@4b360a82{STOPPED,size=0,capacity=UNLIMITED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47206ms DeflaterPool@4b360a82{STARTED,size=0,capacity=UNLIMITED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47206ms GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STARTED,min=32,inflate=-1}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47206ms DeflaterPool@4b360a82{STARTED,size=0,capacity=UNLIMITED}
23/10/16 07:37:40 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: STARTED @47206ms GzipHandler@6c1a6db1{STARTED,min=32,inflate=-1}
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: stopping Server@5817f1ca{STARTED}[9.4.48.v20220622]
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG Server: doStop Server@5817f1ca{STOPPING}[9.4.48.v20220622]
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: stopping Server@5817f1ca{STARTED}[9.4.48.v20220622]
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG Server: doStop Server@5817f1ca{STOPPING}[9.4.48.v20220622]
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG QueuedThreadPool: ran SparkUI-42-acceptor-0@4dd1548e-ServerConnector@78eafad{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040} in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7530090a{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=5,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@2cea921a{reserved=0/4,pending=0}]
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG QueuedThreadPool: ran SparkUI-42-acceptor-0@4dd1548e-ServerConnector@78eafad{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040} in QueuedThreadPool[SparkUI]@7530090a{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=5,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@2cea921a{reserved=0/4,pending=0}]
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractHandlerContainer: Graceful shutdown Server@5817f1ca{STOPPING}[9.4.48.v20220622] by 
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractHandlerContainer: Graceful shutdown Server@5817f1ca{STOPPING}[9.4.48.v20220622] by 
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: stopping Spark@78eafad{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040}
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: stopping Spark@78eafad{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040}
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: stopping SelectorManager@Spark@78eafad{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040}
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@75dd0f94{STARTED} id=1 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: stopping SelectorManager@Spark@78eafad{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:4040}
23/10/16 07:37:42 DEBUG AbstractLifeCycle: stopping ManagedSelector@75dd0f94{STARTED} id=1 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0
```

SparkConf in SparkApplication

```
        "spark.submit.deployMode": "cluster"
        "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Divy.cache.dir=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j/log4j.properties -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED"
        "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j/log4j.properties -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED"
        "spark.decommission.enabled": "true"
        "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true"
        "spark.eventLog.dir": "s3a:<s3_logpath>"
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload": "true"
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider": "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.downgrade.syncable.Exceptions": "true"
        "spark.kubernetes.namespace": "spark"
        "spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt"
        "spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"
        "spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.<env_key>": "<env_value>"
        "spark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix": "<pod_prefix>"
        "spark.kubernetes.submission.connectionTimeout": "100000"
        "spark.kubernetes.submission.requestTimeout": "100000"
        "spark.kubernetes.driver.requestTimeout": "100000"
        "spark.kubernetes.driver.connectionTimeout": "100000"
        "spark.kubernetes.allocation.executor.timeout": "1200s"
        "spark.kubernetes.allocation.driver.readinessTimeout": "60s"
```

And versions are below.

Java 11
Kotlin 1.8.20
scala 2.12
spark 3.3.1
gradle 8.2
kotlinsparkapi 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The reason why quitting my job was kotlin's runCatching. Looks like it catches so many things even though unrelated to program code logic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).